# How to express the parabola $x^2+y^2+2xy-2x-1=0$ in form of SP=PM?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

How to express the parabola $x^2+y^2+2xy-2x-1=0$ in form of SP=PM ?

i.e. like: $$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2= \frac{(mx+ny+c)^2}{m^2+n^2}$$

What is the best method for such a conversion of form of equation ?

Comment: Try $u:=\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $v:=\frac{y-x}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: @Batominovski Can you tell the reason how you got those expressions ? I know it will work, but why ?

Comment: Take your "ideal" equation and expand the quadratic terms. Then match up your ideal to your original equation, and equate the coefficients.

Comment: I'm noticing a problem, that your original equation has 6 coefficients (if you include 0y) and the ideal has 5 unknowns. This may mean you might not be able to find a solution of this form.

Comment: @Kaynex Isn't that a bit too lengthy and complicated....

Comment: It may not be the simplest solution, but it will always work. You could also try assembling the trinomial on the right and then completing the square on the left. You just have to make sure you get rid of that xy term before completing the square.

Comment: @Kaynex It is the toughest solution possible. And I do not wish to spend half an hour on just solving this. There must be an easier way. Let's wait.

Comment: The reason is the $(u,v)$-plane is just the $(x,y)$-plane rotated counterclockwise by $\frac{\pi}{4}$, and this quadratic curve in the $(u,v)$-plane is precisely a parabolic equation in the standard form $v=au^2+bu+c$.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
The equation for the parabola can be written as 
$$(x+y)^2=2x+1$$

Because of the symmetry between $x,y$ in the squared term, we suspect that this may be a parabola rotated by $45^{\circ}$.

If we rotate this by another $45^{\circ}$ clockwise using $(x,y)\rightarrow \frac 1{\sqrt 2}(x-y, x+y)$, we have
$$y=-\sqrt2\left[\left(x-\frac 1{2\sqrt2}\right)^2-\frac 58\right]$$
which is a translated and reflected version of the parabola $y=\sqrt2 x^2$. This parabola can be written as $x^2=4\left(\frac 1{4\sqrt 2}\right)y$, with focus $\left(0,\frac 1{4\sqrt 2}\right)$, directrix $y=-\frac 1{4\sqrt 2}$, vertex $(0,0)$ and axis of symmetry $x=0$.

**Original parabola**

Working back, we find that the original parabola  has **axis of symmetry** $x+y=\frac 12$ and **vertex** $(-\frac 38, \frac 78)$ (where axis of symmetry intersects parabola).

The **focus** lies on the axis of symmetry, $\frac 1{4\sqrt 2}$ away from the vertex, and is given by $$\color{red}{S\left(-\frac14, \frac 34\right)}.$$

The **directrix** passes through a point on the axis of symmetry, $\frac 1{4\sqrt 2}$ from the vertex, and away from the parabola, and is perpendicular to the axis of symmetry. The equation of the directrix is given by $y=x+\frac 32$ or $$2x-2y+3=0.$$

To confirm and state the parabola in $SP=PM$ form as required, note that a **parametric form** of the parabola is $$\color{red}{P(2t^2+2t, 1-2t^2)}$$ which is the coordinate of any point $P$ on the parabola.

We can easily compute that 
$$\color{red}{SP=\frac {8t^2+4t+1}{2\sqrt 2}}$$

Consider the line perpendicular to the directrix passing through $P$ is given by $x+y=2t+1$. The foot of this perpendicular is given by 
$$\color{red}{M\left(t-\frac 14, t+\frac 54\right)}$$

It can be easily verified that 
$$\color{red}{PM=\frac {8t^2+4t+1}{2\sqrt 2}}$$
i.e. $\color{red}{SP=PM}$.

---

NB - It may be helpful to plot the curves on *desmos*.